# Doctrine event not working

Tags: php, symfony, events, doctrine-orm

I use doctrine events (listener and subscriber ), in both of them i have such a problem : when i run postPersist they do not run all the time. I mean in a foreach i call doctrine remove but the event only call once and not more? can some one give me some directions?

Sample code is below:

```
foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
            $entity = $this
                ->findOneBy([$this->primaryKeyName => $value[$this->primaryKeyName]]);
            if($i!=1)
                $this->_em->getEventManager()->dispatchEvent('postUpdate',new LifecycleEventArgs($entity,$this->_em));
            $i++;
            $this->_em->remove($entity);
            $this->_em->flush();

            $result[] = $value;
        }
        return $result;
```

Comment: Persist event happens only once, once the object is saved to the storage for the first time. Saving the object next time postUpdate event is triggered.

Comment: @mike why in example above remove run n-1 times?

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to achieve

Comment: @mike in foreach in my question postremove doctrine event run n-1 time (i mean if foreach steps are n time, then event run n-1 , one time less ) okay?

Comment: I don't know what you mean and still lack knowledge what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: @user2582897 Did you add the @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks annotations to the entity? just to be sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure your persist is out of foreach like below:

```
foreach ($input as $key => $value) {
    $entity = $this
        ->findOneBy([$this->primaryKeyName => $value[$this->primaryKeyName]]);
    $this->_em->remove($entity);
    $result[] = $value;
}
$this->_em->flush();
$this->_em->close();
```

this will call event subscriber postRemove event.